# make composed Link with react-router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

the problem is when I add a composed link for example

`<Route path="L1/L2" component={Comp}/>`

when navigating to the Link the app can't Load the resources from public folder cause the app is loading the resources from example : `http://localhost:8080/L1/bundle.js` instead of `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js`
I guess it's a problem in the webpack configuration but couldn't fix it 
here is my webpack config :

```
    var config = {
      devtool: 'eval-source-map',
      entry:  __dirname + "/app/Index.js",
      output: {
       path: __dirname + "/public",
       filename: "bundle.js"
     },
     module: {
     loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015','react']
      }
    }]
   },
   devServer: {
    contentBase: "./public",
    colors: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    inline: true
   }
```

all help will be appreciated thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about how you load in your bundle in the `index.html`:

- `<script src="bundle.js"></script>` is relative to the **current url**.
- `<script src="/bundle.js"></script>` is relative to the **root**.

Try the second version, it should work then.